# 'Feature' definition

Tags: machine-learning, beginner

Precisely, what is a *feature*? Is it an attribute/property *name* or its *value*?

E.g. would features examples be "name", "adress", ...?
Or "Dorothy", "123 YellowBrick Road"??

If it is a property name, what do you call its corresponding values? ("Feature-values"?)

If it is a value, how do you call its corresponding property name?

In the texts I read, it seems the meaning is interchangeable and depends on context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Feature** in the data science context is the name of your variable, answering your question it would be things like *name*, *address*, *price*, *volume*, etc. It is also known as **attributes, columns, variables**, etc.

Each row in your data set is denominated an **instance**, in your example again, it would be *dorothy*, *123 yellowbric road*, U$12.3, 1000, etc. They might be called just rows, examples, etc.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Now, is there a word for the value taken by a particular feature of an instance (i.e. the "cell" at the intersection of a row (the instance) and a column (the feature)?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You can say its a feature value, or an instance of your feature. I think it will be ok.

Comment: @MonkeyLearning I suppose a more statistical term could be a "realization", which alludes to each feature/column/variable/predictor following an unknown probability distribution and our "observation" being a mere realized value from this distribution.  This is kind of pedantic though and I wouldn't worry too much on this.